# Mapping Date and Time to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, date, time

I have created a table in `MySQL` as :

```
CREATE TABLE scheduled(sid INT,id INT,tweet VARCHAR(255),sdate DATE, 
          stime TIME,PRIMARY KEY(sid),FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES usercred(id));
```

I receive both `Date` and `Time` from the HTML input field. Date received from the HTML field looks like :

```
4/30/2014
```

How can I map this in Java ? After receiving both `Date` and `Time` and after mapping them correctly , I will commit the transaction or will update the table/entry.

Answer (score 0):

In JDBC-layer inside `PreparedStatement` or `ResultSet` you work with the mapping `java.sql.Date` (for SQL-DATE) and `java.sql.Time` (for SQL-TIME). Then you can wrap both types like:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = ...; // from ResultSet
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // or M/d/yyyy
String htmlFormat = df.format(sqlDate);
```

And in reverse:

```
String htmlFormat = ...;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); // or M/d/yyyy
java.util.Date d = df.parse(htmlFormat);
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
// use result in PreparedStatement for INSERT or UPDATE
```

Attention: Both approaches use the standard timezone of the server where this code is running. In case of doubt you should probably set the timezone UTC. Similar code for the TIME-part.

Comment: can you please explain the `parse` method

Comment: @saplingPro The class `SimpleDateFormat` uses a pattern expression in order to interprete string inputs as object of type `java.util.Date`. You can affect this parsing by setting the timezone or the leniency. See also the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), please. Note that there are also better libraries available, but this is very basic stuff since Java 1.

Answer (score 0):

could use the parse() method in the SimpleDateFormat object:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy");
String dateInString = "4-30-1982"";     
Date date = sdf.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
```